# Assigned apk error

Tags: android, android-studio, signed-apk

I have a problem with installing assignet apk, but debug works cool, and tested clean project with my keystore, it's works too
 there my module.app:

[image]
log from logcat:

```
42:11.974 3493-3493/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-24 22:42:11.974 3493-3493/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-24 22:42:12.027 3493-3493/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
```

error in shell:

```
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: Recreate project,copy all data from old project and.....it's works...